# How to get current username information from MySql Database ,C#

Tags: c#, mysql, database, authentication

I have an application with login form, and I want after the login to show on a label or something , the username and other information from my database with that user.

For example , after you login with username "admin" , to show me on next form a text "Welcome Administrator!" . Or if I login with username "john", to show me on next form a text "Welcome John Snow!" .

How I can do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to keep track of a session identifier and use that to track a user through a current session and you could then display that on your GUI through whatever language/api you are using in your application. Alternatively if you don't want to or need to keep track of your user past the login page you could just forward that to the class that handles the next page by allowing the next class to inherit the previous.

However it's hard to get much more specific without more details on your project.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to put the UserName variable in Session and access it in the next page.

Pseudo Code...
In the login page after authentication check write this (assuming 2nd page is Home.aspx):

```
Session["USER_NAME"] = userName;
Respinse.Redirect("Home.aspx");
```

In Home.aspx page_load function, write this  to fetch the name from session and display, and redirect user to login page if no session value present.

```
if(Session["USER_NAME"] != null)
{
    lblUserName.Text = Session["USER_NAME"].ToString();
}
else
{
    Respinse.Redirect("Login.aspx");
}
```